# What is the norm for the product of normed spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(\Omega, \Sigma ,\lambda)$  is a probability space  and $X_i=L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,\lambda ,[0,1])$ with  norm $||.||_{L^2}$  for all $i\in I$, $I$ is finite.

1. Is there any natural norm for the product space $X=\prod_{i\in I} X_i$?
2. Is it possible to generate any norm on $X$ from an inner product   $(. |.)： X \times X\to R$, i.e.

$$(x|y)= \sum_{i\in I}  \int_{\Omega } x_i y_i d\lambda$$

and

$$ ||x|| = \sqrt{\sum_i ||x||^2_{L^2}}=\sqrt{\sum_{i\in I}  \int_{\Omega } x_i^2 d\lambda  }$$?

3. If now I define a vector-valued $L^2$ space $Y=L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,\lambda,[0,1]^I)$ with the norm

$$||y||_Y= \sqrt{\int_{\Omega } \sum_{i\in I}  y_i^2 d\lambda }$$

Is the spaces $Y$ and $X$ equivalent in the sense that each element in $Y$  uniquely corresponds to an element in $X$?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there finitely many $X_i$, or infinitely many? And what does the $[0,1]$ in $L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,\lambda,[0,1])$ mean?

Comment: Hi, $I$ is finite.

Comment: Good, then the product is normable. What about the second question I added to my comment?

Comment: [0,1] is the range of the functions. Another question I am confused is that whether the convergence in norm in $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, I know that $[0,1]$ is the unit interval, but what does it do in $L^2(\Omega,\Sigma,\lambda,[0,1])$? Usually, the data specifying the $L^p$ spaces are (some of) a) the domain of the functions; this is $\Omega$ here, b) the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets; that is $\Sigma$, and c) the measure; that is $\lambda$. Often some of the data are omitted ($\lambda$ determines $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$, so that alone suffices), occasionally tacitly assumed (for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the Lebesgue measure is often tacitly assumed).

Comment: But I have never seen anything else added, except a codomain, which however needs to be a (normed) vector space in order for the $L^p$ space to be a vector space. So taking $[0,1]$ as the codomain would make things not vector spaces.

Comment: I think [0,1] is the codomain of the functions